# Probability of being in same bin in a random clustering scenario

Tags: probability, clustering

I have a set of $N(\geq 2)$ objects which I randomly group in $C(\leq N)$ clusters i.e. all the $C$ clusters have atleast one object and all such clusterings are equally likely.

What is the probability that 2 particular objects from this group of $N$ objects are in same cluster?

Comment: The title says "expectation" and the body says "probability".

Comment: If we "throw" the objects at the bins, then some bins may remain empty. A completely different model is that all $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $x_i\ge 1$ and $\sum x_i=N$ are equally likely. This is an implausible model for any real phenomenon: almost everybody in Bin $1$, and one object in $2$, is far less likely under the throwing model than a more even distribution.

Comment: @joriki : corrected the title.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : I wish to measure performance of my clustering against a random clustering of same granularity and the problem statement is described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is what you ask, but the answer with fixed clusters can be derived in this way:

What is the probability that 2 particular objects belong to the kth cluster?

The probability is the number of manners to combine two individuals from cluster $k$ ($C_k$ is the number of objects on the cluster $k$) divided by the number of manners to combine two individuals from $N$ of them (the total number of pairs).

$(_{2}^{C_k})/(_{2}^{N})$.

What is the probability that the 2 particular objects belong to the same cluster? 
Since the pair belongs to the cluster 1 or cluster 2 or ... or cluster C, we have:

It is the probability that the 2 objects belong to the cluster $1$ (with $C_1$ objects) plus 
the probability that the 2 objects belong to the cluster 2 (with $C_2$ objects) plus ....
plus the probability that the 2 objects belong to in the cluster C (with $C_c$ objects)

$(_{2}^{N})^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^{C} (_{2}^{C_k})$,

where $C$ is the number of clusters.

Edit any error, please!

Comment: Can you explain more clearly please? I am not able to comprehend your explanation. What is C_k?

Comment: Sure. I will edit the answer.

Comment: What did you mean with "the clusters are equally likely"?

Comment: I meant that all "clusterings" i.e distribution of N objects into C clusters are equally likely.

Comment: thus C is fixed.

Comment: Yes. I want the probability for fixed N and C.